# How to get form input using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Instead of PHP, I want to use jQuery to get user input and pass in a function and update a "div".
My HTML(includes scripts) code is:

```
<head>
    <title>Mobile Locale test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Mobile Locale this is!" />
    <script>
        var x;
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            x = $("#q").val();
            var name = "Hello " + x + ". Welcome to this site";
            $("#test").text(name);
        });

        console.log(x);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="q" placeholder="Your name please...">
        <button id="submit">Submit!</button>
        <div id="test">This should change...</div>
    </form>
</body>
```

What I want:
I want to get input from user and assign that input to x.
Then I want to complete a string and pass x in that string.
Then I want to write that complete sentence in div id="test".

I am stumbling this for more than 6 hours but got no success. Tried numerous codes but failed.
Referred w3schools jQuery form example but they are using form method="abcd.asp".

Thanks in advance...

Comment: wrap the script in a named function instead of the document ready function, then call that function with the onclick event of the button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>jquery</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script>

                var x;
                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                   var  x = $("input#q").val();
                    var name = "Hello " + x + ". Welcome to this site";
                    $("#test").text(name);
                });

                function CallSubmit()
                {
                    var  x = $("input#q").val();
                    var name = "Hello " + x + ". Welcome to this site";
                    $("#test").text(name);
                    return false;
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
         <form>
                <input type="text" id="q" placeholder="Your name please...">
                <button id="submit" onclick="return CallSubmit();">Submit!</button>
                <div id="test">This should change...</div>
            </form>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is executed on page load, when the `input` is empty - call the code on an event, like `keyup`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#q").keyup(function() {
    var name = "Hello " + this.value + ". Welcome to this site";
    $("#test").text(name);
  })    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="q" placeholder="Your name please...">
<button id="submit">Submit!</button>
<div id="test">This should change...</div>
```

Comment: But I want to store input value in x. And update the string upon submitting the form.
But you taught me another useful thing. I may use this in future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `focusout`event with the `input` to dynamically change the div. Another approach would be to update on each `keypress`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#q').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                var x = $(this).val();
                var name = "Your string " + x;
            }
            $('#test').text(name);
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/86evwkbx/

Answer (score 0):

You could get the name in the click event of the button.
Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/jjjoeupp/

```
$('#submit').on('click', function()
        {            
            x = $("#q").val();
            var name = "Hello " + x + ". Welcome to this site";
            $("#test").text(name);
        });

Hope it helps!!!
```

Comment: Yes it's working upon clicking on "Submit!" button. How can I make this work after pressing "enter" or "return" ? :)